# Is it possible to format the date by Calculated Value property?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I created a field in list as DOB (Date and Time type).  I want to display DOB in the format of '`1 Oct 2013`'.  How can I achieve this?  Is it possible to do by Calculated Value property?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible by using "Calculated Value" property of "DOB" column as self referral is not allowed.

What you can do is create a new "Calculated" column and then use formula
`=TEXT(DOB,"dd MMM yyyy")`. Select "Date and Time" in data type returned and use "Date only" in format.

This will solve your purpose.

Comment: Better yet, wrap that in an `IF` statement to deal with empty dates. For example: `=IF(DOB<>"",TEXT(DOB,"dd MMM yyyy","")`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can format date in Calculated Field.. Calculated field uses Excel formulas (not all of them are available).. But fortunately you have [TEXT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) which can be used to format dates in Calculated Columns..

For example:

```
TEXT([Created], "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Please see [TEXT Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) for reference

PS: Its better to try your formula in Excel before using it in SharePoint